# My method can't works on list which is recognized out of class

Tags: dart

if i'd try to define list in class ,i was facing another problem so i couldn't take list element length as integer.

Hi guys, this is my first stackoverflow question .I hope I could ask well .

I am trying build an calculator like google's But i am facing a problem . When i call `buton()` method which is recognized in `class mantik`, everything works right except my list=>`List<int> girdi = [];`.

`Buton` method returns `kuvvet_alma` method then `kuvvet_alma` assigns a number to list girdi which is recognized out of class .After that kuvvet_alma should proceed on that list his function but isn't.In a forum , a guy have gave me an advice that was using about "breakpoint" but there is no point i've reached .
To sum up i want to add ints in `List<int> girdi = [];`  and works on them with methods like `kuvvet_alma`  or `tespit` .
Where am i wrong i couldn't get it . I hope i've mentioned well about my problem, thank you everyone who have read it .

```
List<int> girdi = [];
int n = girdi.length;

class mantik {
  void tespit() {
    for (int i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
      var a = pow(10, n - i);
      print(a);
    }
  }

  void kuvvet_alma(int z) {
    girdi.add(z);
    if (girdi.isNotEmpty == true) {
      for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i < 0) {
          print(girdi[n]);
        } else {
          int a = pow(10, i);
          print(girdi[(n - 1) - i] * a);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void buton(int tus) {
   print(girdi);
    return mantik().kuvvet_alma(tus);
  }
}
```

for english meaning: girdi=input ,  mantik=idea,   kuvvet_alma=taking power an integer ,  tespit=determination, buton=button

Comment: There are some errors in your code: (1) `n` starts with `0` but in what place it change its value? (2) What on earth are you trying to do in your `button` method? `kuvvet_alma` method returns nothing so why you use `return` and why create an instance of your own same class? I recommend you to outline your operation through practical examples and then do programming from there.

Comment: A likely first issue is that `mantik().kuvvet_alma(tus)` should be `this.kuvvet_alma(tus)` (or just `kuvvet_alma(tus)`). Maybe try that and see if that helps.